# How to insert a PNG file into an R-Markup

Tags: r

I am doing a homework assignment for a class that asks for the homework to be submitted as an r-markup (as an HTML file). Part of the homework included drawing a physical graph so I have that picture as a PNG file, saved to my desktop.

This is the code I currently have for it - I get an error message when I run the code saying there is an error in the code. I copied the pathway directly from the file itself.

What am I doing wrong?

```
knitr::include_graphics("C:Users/julie/Documents/chart.png")
```

Comment: Maybe just a missing backslash in the file path? Try with `"C:/Users/julie/Documents/chart.png"`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julie,

Just insert the png into your RMarkdown document (outside of an R code block) like:

```
<img src="C:/Users/julie/Documents/chart.png" alt="Chart">
```

When you knit the document to HTML it will show up in there.